# Can Win32::GuiTest detect error popups thrown by Excel?

Tags: perl, win32gui

I am using [Win32::GuiTest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::GuiTest).

Following is my code, I am sending this to an Excel file, the cell in which I am trying to write doesn't allow `20` as a valid value, and throws an exception in the form of a popup.

```
my $command = "{DOWN}{RIGHT}{DOWN}{RIGHT}{DOWN}{RIGHT}{DOWN}";
SendKeys($command);
SendKeys("20");
```

Is there a way to catch those error(code/text) messages using Perl?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says

> SendKeys always returns after sending the keystrokes. There is no way
>   to tell if an application has processed those keys when the function
>   returns.

You might find FindWindowLike and GetChildWindows helpful.

See: http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=282956